# Describe how reversing the orientation of a curve affects the integral C F dot dr?

Tags: calculus

Doesn't it just go the opposite direction? Would I say that C becomes negative then? Help thank you.
[Link to Problem Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsp5T.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbf{F}$ be a vector field whose domain (a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ or perhaps $\mathbb{R}^3$) includes the points on $C$. Let $-C$ be the curve consisting of the same points as $C$ but with opposite orientation.

Answer: $\int_{-C} \mathbf{F} \mathbin{\boldsymbol{\cdot}}d \mathbf{r}$ and $\int_{C} \mathbf{F} \mathbin{\boldsymbol{\cdot}}d \mathbf{r}$ have *opposite* sign:
$$
\int_{-C} \mathbf{F} \mathbin{\boldsymbol{\cdot}}d \mathbf{r} 
= \int_{-C} \mathbf{F} \mathbin{\boldsymbol{\cdot}} \mathbf{T} \, ds
= - \int_{C} \mathbf{F} \mathbin{\boldsymbol{\cdot}} \mathbf{T} \, ds
= - \int_{C} \mathbf{F} \mathbin{\boldsymbol{\cdot}}d \mathbf{r} .
$$
Reason: Let $(x,y,z)$ be any point on $C$ (hence on $-C$). By switching to $-C$, the unit tangent vector $\mathbf{T}(x,y,z)$ on $C$ changes to $- \mathbf{T}(x,y,z)$. This is because the direction of the unit tangent vector at $(x,y,z)$ on $-C$ points in the direction of $-C$, which is opposite its direction on $C$, i.e., opposite of $\mathbf{T}(x,y,z)$.